# Identity Transformation - compare attributes and limit output

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I want to compare the attributes of two xml-Files and identity transform the input file in the same step. The output xml should only contain elements whose attributes occur in the comparing xml. As shown in the given example, the last concept node should not be outputted, as there is no matching attribute in the comparing.xml

**input.xml**

```
<navigation 
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<facets>
    <facet id="d1e12000000000000000000000011111">
        <title xml:lang="en">sometxt</title>
        <title xml:lang="de">eintxt</title>
        <concepts>
            <concept id="d1e12000000000000000000000000000">
                <title xml:lang="en">sometxt</title>
                <title xml:lang="de">eintxt</title>
                <concepts>
                    <concept id="d1e19000000000000000000000000000">
                        <title xml:lang="en">sometxt</title>
                        <title xml:lang="de">eintxt</title>
                        <concepts>
                        </concepts>
                    </concept>
                </concepts>
            </concept>
        </concepts>
    </facet>
</facets>
```

part of **comparing.xml** with indefinite heading-levels

```
<foo>
<heading class="d1e12000000000000000000000011111|d1e12000000000000000000000000000">Myheading</heading>
<chapter>
    <heading class="d1e12000000000000000000000011111|d1e12000000000000000000000000000">myheading</heading>
    <operation>
        <heading class="d1e12000000000000000000000011111|d1e12000000000000000000000000000">another heading</heading>
    </operation>
</chapter>
```

desired **output.xml** with only applicable id's

```
<nav:navigation 
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:nav="http://www.nav.de/">
<nav:facets>
    <nav:facet id="d1e12000000000000000000000011111">
        <nav:title xml:lang="en">sometxt</nav:title>
        <nav:title xml:lang="de">eintxt</nav:title>
        <nav:concepts>
            <nav:concept id="d1e12000000000000000000000000000">
                <nav:title xml:lang="en">sometxt</nav:title>
                <nav:title xml:lang="de">eintxt</nav:title>
                <nav:concepts>
                </nav:concepts>
            </nav:concept>
        </nav:concepts>
    </nav:facet>
</nav:facets>
```

my **xsl** so far

```
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:nav="http://www.nav.de/"
     version="2.0" >
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
        <xsl:variable name="docu" select="document(comparing.xml)"/>

        <xsl:template match="*">
            <xsl:element name="nav:{name()}" namespace="http://www.nav.de/">
                <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
```

EDIT: sorry for posting this in the comment-section. I've tried something along those lines, but it didn't work

```
   <xsl:template match="concept | facet">
        <xsl:variable name="foo-id" select="@id"/>  
        <xsl:for-each select="$docu//heading">
            <xsl:if test="contains(./@class, $foo-id)">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>  
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: **1.** Do you have control over the format of `comparing.xml`? The use of a "|" delimited list is an unnecessary complication. If you're using XML, use it properly and put each value in a separate node. --  **2.** Are you supposed to compare the given `id` to **any** `class` value - regardless of parent or level?

Comment: **1.** unfortunately I have no control over the format, sorry.
**2.** exactly! like: If `class` contains `id`, then output the `<nav:facet>` or `<nav:concept>` elements; if not, then don't output them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you try it this way:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:nav="http://www.nav.de/">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="comparing-url" select="'comparing.xml'"/>

<xsl:key name="comp" match="@class" use="tokenize(., '\|')" />

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="nav:{name()}" >
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@id][not(key('comp', @id, document($comparing-url)))]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your Suggestion! I get the error `SXLM0001: Too many nested apply-template calls. The stylesheet may be looping.`

Comment: @TR9000 It works for me here using Saxon 8.9. Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: mhh I'm using saxon9he

Comment: Are you sure you are trying this with my stylesheet (with no additions) and the provided input?

Comment: my bad, sorry! Forgot to delete the previous identity transformation. Needed to clean my stylesheet. Would you mind to edit your answer and delete the `<xsl:apply-templates/>` within the second `<xsl:template>`. Otherwise it will output child elements of the deleted elements. Now it works fine for me, thank you!

Comment: Ah, I see. I got confused because all your text nodes are the same. Fixed now.